# kubuntu 10.04 + ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports - is it really stable enough?

Tags: 10.04, ppa, kubuntu

I have kubuntu 10.04 32bit. I'm having some problems with some kde apps.
I have read around that installing the updates from the  ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports would help.

I know that the kubuntu ppa are unofficial ubuntu repo but are directly maintained by the kubuntu team, to provide important updates to the kubuntu users
https://wiki.kubuntu.org/Kubuntu/KubuntuPPAs
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Kubuntu

I'd like to know from other people that have kubuntu 10.04 + ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports.
**Is this solution working really well? Is it stable enough?**

I'm confused 'cause if I add the repository, and take a look on what an update what do, I have different results if I check with kpakagekit or with aptitude

**packagekit**

- update 116 packages
- 26 packages will be marked as blocked (network-manager kdebase-bin plasma-widgets-workspace)

**aptitude**

- 82 packages to install
- 13 packages to delete (kdebase-plasma kdepimlibs-data ecc)
- 142 packages to update

**wich program should I use to do this? Aptidude ore KPackageKit?**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I enabled the  ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports and i run the update.

All my bugs are still there, plus OpenOffice is not working anymore.

These is more than enough.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use 10.04 in the first place? There are newer versions. Perhaps you would want to have a look at 11.10, for instance?

Comment: 10.04 is a LTS, on my office workstation I use to install LTS 'cause they should me more solid, and it will pass more time before I need to upgrade from a LTS to another (nearly 3 years)

Comment: No, it will be less solid if you start adding PPAs. And LTSes are supposed to be supported _longer_. Non-LTS releases are just as stable, except they'll need to be upgraded after 18 months instead of 36.